# How to call api from shared data-access library in NX, Monorepo

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx

Can anyone please help in understanding How to call api from shared data-access library in NX, Monorepo.

I have component in feature library which would like to access api. Should we access api from api folder under APPs or can we make it from data-access library of the application.

Thanks in Advance